# .NET Library For Fixed Length Text Files

Tags: .net, file, fixed-length-record, structured-data

I'm looking for a .NET (much preferably open source in C#) library for dealing with fixed length field text files.  It wouldn't be too much to write one, but existing, tested work is always nicer, to start with.

I will be extracting data in fixed length fields from files produced by a PBX.  Each PBX has its own file format, as well a set of record formats.  I'm looking for a library with a nice a simple way of using dynamic file and record formats, e.g. read from an INI or XML file.

**EDIT:**  I had previously overlooked Marcos Meli' great library [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/), because I thought I needed to create a class for each record type at compile time.  This is not so, and the lib includes a `ClassBuilder` class to build classes at runtime.

**NEW EDIT:**  Records from different PBX's differ only in layout, not in data, i.e. all the record layouts map to the same class.  I'm wondering if I should use FileHelper attributes that dynamically read their start and length data from a config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since been pointed to this [XML based parsing code](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6156780.html), as well as this [similar project on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ReportParser.aspx).  The more the merrier, and the closer I will get to a 'perfect' fit.